# asp.net 3.5 + update panel doesn't work in mozilla

Tags: asp.net, firefox, updatepanel

I show/hide few images basing on the button clicks in update panel. I use an update progress also for this. Everything works fine in IE7. But in Firefox Version 3.0.14 when I click on the button in the update panel the event itself is not getting fired.

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. This is because, I didn't set the CausesValidation property to false. I need this because there are usercontrols which performs their own validations.

But now, I am wondering why IE allowed the button click?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any reason for it to work in IE and not in FF.
What plugins you have installed on Firefox?
**Disable all plugins and then check.**

Comment: Even after disabling the plugins I am getting the same problem